# Force between two skew (non-parallel) straight current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

The force between two **parallel** straight wires carrying the same current is calculated in every textbook. The force per length changes with 1/r, r being the wire distance.

I understand that the force, if the two straight wires are **perpendicular** to each other, is **zero**.

What is the force if the straight wires are at an **arbitrary angle**? Above all, how does it change with distance r? (In this case, r would be the distance of the closest approach.) Scaling intuition would suggest that the force still changes with 1/r, like the parallel case, but with a smaller prefactor. (Again, both wires have the same current.) Is this correct?

---

EDIT: the reason for the question was that there is a possible analogy between the attraction between two skew current wires to a candidate explanation for the MOND relation for stars at the outskirts of galaxies, for which the force is conjectured to decay as 1/r. In this analogy, the two skew directions are the rotation axes of the galaxy and of the outer star.

Therefore, the question was whether 1/r really is the relation for current-carrying wires. (Note that the original question was a yes-no question, and no calculations were required or asked for.)

Comment: There is a nice problem in Griffiths (5.10). It deals with the force on a triangle loop by a magnetic field created by an infinite current line. It's interesting since the force on the sides that are not parallel to the current goes like $\log(1+1/r)$.

Comment: @sazan Thank you. In fact, I only wanted to know whether the force changes as 1/r or in another way. The problem you mention differs because the wires have finite length. The original question was for finite length. (Bc the way: is that a "one" or an "ell" in for formula?)

Comment: @saza For get my last question, it is a "one" of course.